# How to pass a script to gnome-terminal in one file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, gnome-terminal

I currently work in hardware development, at present frequently connecting/disconnecting/rebooting device(s) connected to the serial ports. (Usually just /dev/ttyUSB0)

I have a basic script to monitor the serial port, which runs in its own small `gnome-terminal` window in one corner of my screen, so I can "at-a-glance" easily see if a device is connected, or has finished rebooting etc. This window is visble all the time. for monitoring purposes.

The script (`monitorSerialPorts`) is basic but functional:

```
while [ true ] 
do
  clear
  printf "\n Serial Devices: "
  ls /dev/ttyUSB* 2> /dev/null || (clear ; printf "\n  No Devices Detected")
  sleep 2
done
```

And I call this script from a second script (`monitorSerialPortsLauncher`), that runs upon login, the contents is just one line, which creates a small window nicely where I need it:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=RedonYellow --command=$HOME/scripts/monitorSerialPorts --geometry=26x3-20
```

Question: is there a *clean* way to combine this functionality in to a single script? 
(Also, any overall suggestions for improvements to this process or script are welcomed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put in this script in your monitorSerialPortsLauncher

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
script=/tmp/monitorSerialPorts
cat << 'EOF' > $script
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sleep 10
while true
do
  clear
  printf "\n Serial Devices: "
  ls /dev/ttyUSB* 2> /dev/null || (clear ; printf "\n  No Devices Detected")
  sleep 2
done
EOF
chmod 755 $script
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=RedonYellow --geometry=60x6-20 --command="$script"
```